# multiple json requests with accumulated result

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to create several html elements that need to wait for a getJSON request from wikipedia. Here is how i am doing it:

```
$.each(urls, function (i, url) {
                            jxhr.push(
                                $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
                                    alert("inside: " + i);
                                    wikiHTML = json.parse.text["*"];
                                    $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+ wikiHTML+ "</document>");

                                    pages += '<div class="f-page">';
                                    pages += '<div class="f-title">';
                                    pages += '<a href="index.jsp">Back to bookshelf</a>';
                                    pages += '<h2 id="event_name">Your Interests</h2>';
                                    pages += '<a href="#"></a>';
                                    pages += '</div>';

                                    pages += '<div class="box w-50 h-100">';
                                        pages += '<div class="img-cont img-1"></div>';
                                        pages += '<h3>' + interests[i].name + '</h3>';

                                    pages += $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html();

                                    pages += '</div>';
                                })
                            );
                        });

                        $.when.apply($, jxhr).done(function() {
                            alert("inside last");
                            result_html += pages;
                            result_html += '<div class="f-page f-cover-back">';
                            result_html += '<div id="codrops-ad-wrapper"><a href="index.jsp" >Back to bookshelf</a></div>';
                            result_html += '</div>';
                            $('.container').append(result_html);
                        });
```

The problem is that it never enters in the `$.when.apply`.. Is it because the request never finished? is there a problem if one of the requests inside the getJSON fails?

Also i am using **jquery 1.10.2**

also this code is inside:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {

});
```

function

Answer (score 0):

Try making the calls in the `$.each()` loop synchronous and then just do the code in the `.done()` function afterwords:

```
$.each(urls, function (i, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function (json) {
            alert("inside: " + i);
            wikiHTML = json.parse.text["*"];
            $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+ wikiHTML+ "</document>");

            pages += '<div class="f-page">';
            pages += '<div class="f-title">';
            pages += '<a href="index.jsp">Back to bookshelf</a>';
            pages += '<h2 id="event_name">Your Interests</h2>';
            pages += '<a href="#"></a>';
            pages += '</div>';

            pages += '<div class="box w-50 h-100">';
                pages += '<div class="img-cont img-1"></div>';
                pages += '<h3>' + interests[i].name + '</h3>';

            pages += $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html();

            pages += '</div>';
        }
    });
});

alert("inside last");
result_html += pages;
result_html += '<div class="f-page f-cover-back">';
result_html += '<div id="codrops-ad-wrapper"><a href="index.jsp" >Back to bookshelf</a></div>';
result_html += '</div>';
$('.container').append(result_html);
```

---

**Old answer**

Try adding the `.done()` function directly to the `$.getJSON()` call (as they do in the example in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)):

```
$.each(urls, function (i, url) {
                            jxhr.push(
                                $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
                                    alert("inside: " + i);
                                    wikiHTML = json.parse.text["*"];
                                    $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+ wikiHTML+ "</document>");

                                    pages += '<div class="f-page">';
                                    pages += '<div class="f-title">';
                                    pages += '<a href="index.jsp">Back to bookshelf</a>';
                                    pages += '<h2 id="event_name">Your Interests</h2>';
                                    pages += '<a href="#"></a>';
                                    pages += '</div>';

                                    pages += '<div class="box w-50 h-100">';
                                        pages += '<div class="img-cont img-1"></div>';
                                        pages += '<h3>' + interests[i].name + '</h3>';

                                    pages += $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html();

                                    pages += '</div>';
                                }).done(function() {
                                    alert("inside last");
                                    result_html += pages;
                                    result_html += '<div class="f-page f-cover-back">';
                                    result_html += '<div id="codrops-ad-wrapper"><a href="index.jsp" >Back to bookshelf</a></div>';
                                    result_html += '</div>';
                                    $('.container').append(result_html);
                                });
                            );
                        });
```

Comment: but then, result_html isn't done when all the getJSON requests are performed but for every getJSon request, which is not what i want.

Comment: @João I've updated my answer with a new suggestion making the calls asynchronous, if that may work for you?

Comment: u made it sinchronous.

Comment: now i am getting cross origin problem i tried with dataType: "jsonp", in ajax request but didnt work

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Typo... You didn't det that before I guess? Weird, since as far as know `$.getJSON()` is just a shorthand wrapper function of `$.ajax()`. What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Joshua%20Ledet&redirects&prop=text&callback=?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://accessible-serv.lasige.di.fc.ul.pt:42080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: wuth getJSON i dont get it

Comment: I think I know why. `$.ajax()` defaults to `POST`, you're probably just allowed to access though `GET`. I'll edit...

Comment: Sorry, it defaults `GET`actually. I remembered wrong.